# Personalizing date field based on language / locale

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are sending multilingual emails across the globe. We would like to know if there is an existing function or another solution that we can use to localise the dates based on a  date value that is in a data extension. As an example, if we have a date 10/23/2017 in a data extension and we would like to dynamically display this date as follows in French "23 Octobre 2017", what would be the best solution to handle this so that the same email can be used for multiple languages. 
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to take the Country/location data and have it linked to a [culture code](http://www.basicdatepicker.com/samples/cultureinfo.aspx).  From this you can then use [FormatDate(1, 2, 3, 4)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatDate.htm)

For example:

```
%%[

SET @Country = ATTRIBUTEVALUE("Country")
SET @cultureCode = LOOKUP(@cultureFormatDE, "cultureCode", "Country", @Country)
SET @dateFormat = LOOKUP(@cultureFormatDE, "dateFormat", "Country", @Country)
SET @timeFormat = LOOKUP(@cultureFormatDE, "timeFormat", "Country", @Country)

SET @Date = FormatDate(@yourDate, @dateFormat, @timeFormat, @cultureCode)

]%%

%%=v(@Date)=%%
```

If we can assume the country is France, we would use the lookups to collect the following values from the cultureFormatDE, assuming you want the long format (can likely use the info from the link I provided for culture codes):

```
@cultureCode = "fr-FR"
@dateFormat = "dddd d MMMM yyyy"
@timeFormat = "HH:mm"
```

Creating:

```
@Date = FormatDate("10/23/2017", "ddd d MMMM yyyy", "HH:MM", "fr-FR")
```

Which would output

> "lun. 23 octobre 2017 00:00"

**(If you want to remove the time part, just replace "HH:mm" with "")**

If the formats in the linked page do not match exactly what you want, you would likely need to create your own DE to pull this info from for the AMPScript. I also would set a default in case @Country is empty or not recognized.